# Passing parameters to Liferay PortletURL

Tags: liferay, portlet

I would like to validate the request of an user by doing he types his personal key. First of all he does the request, now the portlet redirects to a second jsp file where he validates with the key and finally if it is ok the portlet complete the request otherwise returns to the first step.

Here is the code,

1.- view.jsp (the request)

```
<%@ include file="/html/blue/init.jsp" %>

Welcome to our Colors workflow
<br/>

<% 
PortletURL redirectURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
redirectURL.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "redirect");
%>

<aui:form name="fmAdd" method="POST" action="<%= redirectURL.toString() %>">
<aui:input type="hidden" name="myaction" value="add" />
<aui:button type="submit" value="Add New Box"/>
</aui:form>
&nbsp;
<aui:form name="fmList" method="POST" action="<%= redirectURL.toString() %>">
<aui:input type="hidden" name="myaction" value="list" />
<aui:button type="submit" value="Show All Boxes"/>
</aui:form>
```

2.- the java code,

```
public void redirect(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    String action = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "myaction");

    PortletURL redirectURL = null;
    String redirectJSP = "/checkuser.jsp";
    if(action != null) {
        String portletName = (String)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        redirectURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest),
                portletName, themeDisplay.getLayout().getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
        redirectURL.setParameter("myaction", action);
        redirectURL.setParameter("jspPage", redirectJSP);
    }

    actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirectURL.toString());
}
```

3._ checkuser.jsp (the user validate with his key)

```
<%@ include file="/html/blue/init.jsp" %>

<% 
PortletURL checkUserURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
checkUserURL.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "checkUser");

String myaction = renderRequest.getParameter("myaction");
%>

<p> Your action:&nbsp;<%= myaction %> </p>

<aui:form name="fm" method="POST" action="<%= checkUserURL.toString() %>">
<aui:input type="hidden" name="myaction" value="<%= myaction %>" />
<aui:input type="text" name="key" value=""/>
<aui:button type="submit" value="Save"/>
</aui:form>
```

In this phase I am getting the first problem because I do not see the value of the request (myaction variable). This is only for debug.

4._ the java code that catches the last form,

```
public void checkUser(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    String key = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "key");
    String action = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "myaction");

    String portletName = (String)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    PortletURL redirectURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest),
            portletName, themeDisplay.getLayout().getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);

    String redirectJSP = "/view.jsp";
    if(key != null) {
        if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")) {
            if(action != null) {
                if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                    redirectJSP = "/update.jsp";
                }
                if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
                    redirectJSP = "/list.jsp";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    redirectURL.setParameter("jspPage", redirectJSP);
    actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirectURL.toString());
}
```

In this phase the portlet always goes to view.jsp where the user does the request. I am thinking both key and action variables are null or at least one of them.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Jose

Answer (score 2):

In Liferay, the parameters are set with a namespace so that they don't cause problems when there are more than 1 portlet on the page. Especially if you have the exact same portlet on the page twice! So when you're setting `myaction`, it really gets set to something like `_myportlet_INSTANCE_xlka_myaction` or something similar.

You can use `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil` to help you get your parameters without having to worry about the scoping. For example:

```
ParamUtil.getString(request, "myaction");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what you say and add the following code, `if(null == myaction) myaction = "list"` but still does not work. Having that the variable still does not appear in the jsp portlet. I think there must be something wrong behind the scene in the java code.

Comment: Yes it works. My fault was not to pass the complete path to the jsp files `/html/blue/(jsp file)`. Thanks again for your help.